# Django Rest Framework and Angularjs authentification

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with Authentification throw Django REST API. The front end is seperated from the backend. the front end runs on a server port 8008 and backend on Django 8000. The problem is I added CORS settings in the setting.py and My issue is The api works fine except if I want to access data that requires authentification. This is the authentification Class View:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def get(self, request, format=None):
    print('executed scc!!!')
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }

    return Response(content)

def post(self, request):
    print('Loging in !!!')
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
    django_login(request, user)
    print(request.user)
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({"token": token.key}, status=200)
```

I think the Class view is correct. And it works fine after sending user credentials throw post request. My issue is I have another Class view that requires the user to be authenticated. so when I use postman it works fine I access request.user and it returns the logged in user. But with code I get 
 argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'.

Do I need to add headers to my HTTP requests ? because I've noticed postman uses cookies

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8008',
)
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8008',
)
```

Comment: Can you share your REST configuration in settings?

Comment: I added the settings

Answer (score 0):

You use these authentications:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

Token: you must get the token from the server and add a header in every request like this example (from the docs):

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Session: from the frontend you must log in and get the cookie set after the login. Check the client and see if `sessionid` and the `csrf` are a registered key value in your cookie. (Use the plugin `Awesome Cookie Manager` available for firefox and chrome).
The `csrf` is a token necessary for every dangerous HTTP method (POST, PUT, DELETE...) and must be set as a cookie from the server.

Basic: the basic authentication is just used for testing, I don't even use that in my settings.

All the details are here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

The CORS are setup in the wrong way.

Try these:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

# A list of regexes that match origin regex list of origin hostnames
# that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
    r'^(https?://)?(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|0\.0\.0\.0)(:\d{4})?$',
)

# Check here: 
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I'll do as you said. I just have one question I'm confused is the csrf token same as user token. Because after login I do get user token from backend. And how can I set up cookies using angularjs? Thank you

Comment: The csrf token is used on the Session authentication, you should decide what to use: Session or Token? The cookies are setup by the server and the client send the cookies on every call. You should not do anything when you use the cookies (on the Session authentication)

Comment: One thing I forgot about the CSRF token. If you use a session, remember to use the CSRF token in the header when you do dangerous request. Check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-is-false

Comment: still not working! I still getting this error:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this in the front end:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```